# Linear application of $T(x,y,z)=(x-y,x+z,x+2y)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a problem with four potential linear applications. I just want to learn how to do it for one and then apply it to the others.

> **Problem:** $T:\textbf{R}^3 \to \textbf{R}^3$, $T(x,y,z)=(x-y,x+z,x+2y)$
>
> - Is the application linear?
> - If it is find (a) A matrix representation with respect to a basis of your choice, (b) A basis of Ker(T), and (c) A basis of Im(T).

Comment: **a)** You can easily show that if  $ \vec{a}=(x,y,z), \vec{b}=(u,v,w)$ are elements in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then $T(\vec{a}+\vec{b})=T(\vec{a})+T(\vec{b})$ and for each $\lambda \in \mathbb{R} \text { and } \vec{a}=(x,y,z)$ it is true that $T(\lambda\vec{a})=\lambda T(\vec{a})$.

Comment: **b)** I guess that you already know that $\ker T=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3:T(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)\}$. You need to define the relations among $x,y,z$ and then you can find easily a basis for $\ker (T)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Yes, it is linear. Just prove the conditions for linear maps:

A map $T:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is linear if for all $v,w \in \mathbb R$,$\lambda \in \mathbb R$ holds:

$T(v+w)=T(v)+T(w)$ and $T(\lambda v)=\lambda T(v)$

2) a)

Take a closer look at to map and the matrix operations. You can easily see that the matrix is:

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 0  \end{pmatrix}  $

Because

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 0  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} =T(x,y,z)$

**Question**: Which basis did i choose?

b)

You have to find the set of all $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3$ such that $T(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)^T$

We consider

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 0  \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$

With elementary-row operations on the matrix above you will obtain:

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & -3  \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$

**Question**: Can you tell me know which $(x,y,z)$ fulfills the condition?

c)

If we just want to have a set of vectors which span the image, then it would be enough to take the column-vectors. But we want to have linear-independent vectors, which span our image.

What we have to do now: Consider $T^{T}$[tranposed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) matrix of T and apply the [Gaussian-elemination-algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) on it. The columns which you will obtain then form a basis of the image.

Now its up to you to do that and show us your result.